# Warning: getSymbols, tq_get, getSymbols.yahoo does not return prices for to date

Tags: r, quantmod, tidyquant

This is really more of a warning, but I do ask and answer a question.  When the `to` date parameter is specified in `getSymbols`, `tq_get`, `getSymbols`, the function returns prices for the dates up to but not including the to date even though the documentation (`quantmod::getSymbols.yahoo`) states it will "Retrieve data through this date".  Consider the following example taken from a [tidyquant vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyquant/vignettes/TQ05-performance-analysis-with-tidyquant.html#table.stats):

```
Ra <- c("AAPL", "GOOG", "NFLX") %>%
tq_get(get  = "stock.prices",
       from = "2010-01-01",
       to   = "2015-12-31")
```

One might expect the result to include prices for 2015-12-31, but it only returns prices through 2015-12-30.  There are prices for the 31st; the market was open and the prices can be viewed on [yahoo finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1=1450587600&period2=1451538000&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d).

Documentation, such as the tidyquant vignette, frequently shows the result only of the head function, so this is an easy detail to miss.  If in this example, you wanted performance for 2015, you'd be missing a day.

So for the question: How do I get these functions to return prices up to and including the `to` date parameter?

Comment: This appears to be an issue with the data Yahoo supplies. https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/211 https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/258

Comment: I understand this is a Yahoo issue.  The point of the post is to warn others of what may be unexpected behavior and how it might be avoided.  The  point is not to change the functions.

Comment: It was just to add contextual information for others coming across this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that the `getSymbols` function with source `yahoo`, returns an index.class of type `Date`. If you source your data from Tiingo the index.class returned is of type `POSIXct` and you get the data up and including the “from date” as expected. I.e.

```
getSymbols("AAPL", src = "tiingo", to = "2015-12-31", api.key = "xxx"); tail(AAPL)
[1] "AAPL"
           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume
2015-12-23    107.27    108.85 107.2000     108.61    32657354
2015-12-24    109.00    109.00 107.9500     108.03    13596680
2015-12-28    107.59    107.69 106.1807     106.82    26704210
2015-12-29    106.96    109.43 106.8600     108.74    30931243
2015-12-30    108.58    108.70 107.1800     107.32    25213777
2015-12-31    107.01    107.03 104.8200     105.26    40912316
```

(attention: put in your personal api.token from Tiingo, instead of the 3 ‘x’ in my example)

Check: `?getSymbols.tiingo` , which is meant to be called internally by `getSymbols` only. This method is not meant to be called directly, instead with a call to `getSymbols("x", src="tiingo”)`.

If you want to go with Yahoo data the simple solution is to leave out the `to` argument and subset the data to your desired end date:

```
tail(getSymbols('AAPL',auto.assign = F)['::2015-12-31'])
           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
2015-12-23    107.27    108.85   107.20     108.61    32657400     103.01801
2015-12-24    109.00    109.00   107.95     108.03    13570400     102.46785
2015-12-28    107.59    107.69   106.18     106.82    26704200     101.32014
2015-12-29    106.96    109.43   106.86     108.74    30931200     103.14129
2015-12-30    108.58    108.70   107.18     107.32    25213800     101.79442
2015-12-31    107.01    107.03   104.82     105.26    40635300      99.84048
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to add a day to the `to` date parameter. I have tried changing my timezone to UTC without effect.  In the example make the `to` parameter:

> as.Date("2015-12-31") + lubridate::days(1)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

```
getSymbols("xxx",src="yahoo",from=xxx,to=end,periodicity="daily")
where end=Sys.Dat()+10
```

That's when I got the current day's price

Comment: Maybe you should give more explanations or details!

Comment: Well , for some reason the stock data returned did not include today. It stopped short a few days earlier. So I added 10 days as in Sys.Date+10 ...and that did the trick. 
For example set from=“2019-01-01” and to=Sys.Date()+10
And that returned the prices from Jan 1 2019 to today